# How to play multiple sound files at the same milisecond in pygame?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, pygame

Im trying to play 6 sound files (aiff), 5 mb each, simultaneously, or the closest they can be to the same miliseconds. But my code results in a mess : Some sounds are played indeed simultandeously, but some are not. You can hear 3 sounds being played at diferent times. So ... its like the 6 sounds were divided into 3 groups of 2 sounds, resulting into those 3 sounds at diferent time. This got be a clue...

The files are stored in the ram memory ( since i`m using a live lubuntu image loaded into ram), so its pretty fast, and i assume its no a lag problem. Even because when i loaded the sounds stored in a pendrive, the results sounded exactly the same. SO definetly not a problem here.

```
import pygame as pg
pg.init()
pg.mixer.set_num_channels(50)
pg.mixer.Channel(1).play(pg.mixer.Sound('/home/lubuntu/Piano.pp.B2.aiff'))
pg.mixer.Channel(2).play(pg.mixer.Sound('/home/lubuntu/Piano.pp.A3.aiff'))
pg.mixer.Channel(3).play(pg.mixer.Sound('/home/lubuntu/Piano.pp.A4.aiff'))
pg.mixer.Channel(4).play(pg.mixer.Sound('/home/lubuntu/Piano.pp.A5.aiff'))
pg.mixer.Channel(5).play(pg.mixer.Sound('/home/lubuntu/Piano.pp.A6.aiff'))
pg.mixer.Channel(6).play(pg.mixer.Sound('/home/lubuntu/Piano.pp.A1.aiff'))
```

Comment: This ain't really a direct solution but You could combine those audio files using some audio editor and that way they should certainly play at the same time

Comment: @Matiiss , Yeah, If there is a library or something that can merge sounds in the code, then yes. But i still would need make the code delete it later. But if no one answers a better alternative, this would do. Thanks

Comment: I didn't mean for You to use a library to merge sound, I meant that You could edit Yourself those audiofiles together using some video or audio editor, like Freemake sth or Audacity, however You can probably use some library too

Comment: I would try loading each pg.mixer.Sound() item into an array (or 6 variables) then doing the play(). That might minimize some load penalty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing by loading your 6 sound files from:

http://theremin.music.uiowa.edu/MISpiano.html

I suspect that calling each play() that then calls it's own load() is creating your staggered effect as play2 cannot even think about starting to load it's sound until after play1 is already playing.

```
import pygame as pg
import time

pg.init()
pg.mixer.set_num_channels(50)

foo = [
    pg.mixer.Sound("Piano.pp.A1.aiff"),
    ##pg.mixer.Sound("Piano.pp.A2.aiff"),
    pg.mixer.Sound("Piano.pp.A3.aiff"),
    pg.mixer.Sound("Piano.pp.A4.aiff"),
    pg.mixer.Sound("Piano.pp.A5.aiff"),
    pg.mixer.Sound("Piano.pp.A5.aiff"),
    pg.mixer.Sound("Piano.pp.B2.aiff"),
]

for i,x in enumerate(foo):
    pg.mixer.Channel(i+1).play(x)

time.sleep(10) ## so you can hear something rather than having the app just quit
```

I think this produces more or less what I hear when I open those 6 files in audacity and play them together. Just a heads up that they seem to be mostly silence.

Comment: Weird. I tried your song with your code and then with mine code. Your songs gets better with your code indeed, tho grungy as you said. Then i tried my sounds with your code and then with my code, and they sounded exactly the same. I got my sounds from http://theremin.music.uiowa.edu/MISpiano.html , in case you want to test. Everyone is mostly the same thing.

Comment: sure thing. sorry for the bummer answer

Comment: Ah, nevermind. Im stupid. Just realized the audios im using start at a diferent time, so the reason they sound exactaly the same in your code is because they are producing this bad sync ... Thanks anyway. I`ll be using your code a lot

Comment: Those files seem to be almost entirely silent. Is that what you expected. As for the staggered playing of the first few notes, that seems to be an artifact of the sound files rather than playing them. If I open all 6 tracks in "audacity" and play them together I get basically the same result as my for loop.  Will update the code based on what I tested with